# Merge graphs in JGraphT

Tags: java, jgrapht

I'm using JGraphT and I have two `DirectedGraph` : `g1` and `g2`.

How can I merge `g1` and `g2` to a third graph `g3`? 
I need `g3` be a normal graph and has the ability to add new edges and vertices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found it !

There is a method in `Graphs` class that adds the second entry graph to the first entry graph:

```
Graphs.addGraph(g1, g2);
```

> Adds all the vertices and all the edges of the specified source graph
>   to the specified destination graph. First all vertices of the source
>   graph are added to the destination graph. Then every edge of the
>   source graph is added to the destination graph. This method returns
>   true if the destination graph has been modified as a result of this
>   operation, otherwise it returns false.

We can read more [here](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/Graphs.html#addGraph%28org.jgrapht.Graph,%20org.jgrapht.Graph%29).

Comment: Just to save a click: addGraphReversed​(Graph<? super V,​? super E> destination, Graph<V,​E> source), so g1 is the destination and g2 is the source.